# How do I create a popup Jquery-mobile window with multiple pages that can be swiped through

Tags: jquery, carousel, swipe, jquery-mobile-popup

I am trying to create a popup control area on a tablet interface, and am an experienced programmer, just have never done web based programming before in any serious way.

I have a black bar (will eventually be status information) that when tapped pushes up as a overlay over the bottom 40% of the screen. Within this I want to have several pages of information that can be paged through by swiping horizontally with the number of pages being dependent on which add-ons have been installed.

Each page will by web pages with controls that can be dragged into the main portion of the page, or input controls for entering or updating information.

I would like to use the Jquery-mobile ability to have multiple pages loaded and then switch between them in the popup so there isn't a loading wait. The update of input and data will be done by Ajax-json call responses.

I am running into problems trying to figure out how to do the carousel of web pages, the few carousel JS libraries I have tried seem to work oddly with the popup/swipe interface.

Any recomendations on what is the best way to do this, or examples of what I am trying to do?

Thanks
- Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for some swipe libraries?

- http://jgestures.codeplex.com/
- http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/

Comment: I am using Touch swipe for the swiping, and calling Next/prev on the carousel, just not working well. Mostly looking for information on how to do it using the "best practices" for Jquery-mobile.   I Am new to the web programming, and not sure how to lay out the divs/ other layout information to do what i want. I have muddled through by looking at examples on the jquery-mobile site. But haven't figured out how to do a carousel that works in the "mobile way". I am not really sure what questions i need to ask, I have a vision of what i want it to work like, but not sure how to make that reality.

Comment: While I LOVE me some jQuery I can't say I'm a big fan of jQuery mobile. Do you have to use jQuery mobile?

Comment: The main clients will be tablets. The mobile seemed like a good fit for this. Do you have a better suggestion? Why do you dislike the mobile?

Comment: I guess since I've been a web developer for so long I don't need jQuery Mobile to automatically position all my stuff for me. I just feel very confined when I work with jQuery Mobile. I think you'd be better off building your own site and using CSS to detect browser size n what not so that it will scale nicely when rotated. jQuery mobile is just extra load time you don't really need also.